# PostgreSQL get highest value with certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

**Sample Database Table called test**

[image]

I am trying to get the row that has "the highest priority" within "the last and same height"

Here is what I have tried so far

I first tried getting the "highest priority in the table" and I successfully got the result by using the query below

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) FROM test)
```

Now, I thought this query would work but this throws an error message.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) FROM test ORDER BY height DESC)
```

> ERROR:  column "t2.height" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Can anyone guide me how to solve this?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @fa06 from the sample database, I am expecting to get row number 10 `id = 10, height = 2, priority = 480`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using correlated subquery

```
select * from test a where exists 
 (select 1 from test b  
   where a.height=b.height group by b.height having max(b.priority)=a.priority)
order by height desc
```

Comment: I got it by using this query below. 
`SELECT id, height, max(priority)
from test
group by height order by height desc limit 1
`
Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: does this gives you id no 10? @JayBKim

Comment: Sorry to reply late. Just came back from having lunch. I just ran this query, and it is taking a long time. I stopped it after 2 minutes of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would use `distinct on` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (height) t.*
from t
order by height, priority desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:-

```
SELECT id, height, max(priority)
from test
group by height
```

Comment: How can I order height in a descending order?

Comment: I got it !
`SELECT id, height, max(priority)
from test
group by height order by height desc limit 1
`

Comment: That is an invalid GROUP BY usage